# Unit Testing Action<T>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am using xUnit and MOQ and I am trying to test this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

I have tried this, but no deal:

```
[Fact]
    public void ForEach()
    {
        var list = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2" };

        list.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x += "-passed";
        });

        foreach (var item in list)
            item.Should().EndWith("-passed");
    }
```

How would you go about testing this?

Comment: Note that in your example test you're neither mutating the list, nor any of the items in the list.  You're only mutating the loop variable.  In that case the method is doing exactly what it should, you're just using it improperly.

Answer (score 1):

In your current test, you are only modifying the local `x` variable in your action. I would create a new list:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2" };
var dest = new List<string>();

list.ForEach(s => { dest.Add(x + "-passed"); });

foreach (var item in dest)
{
    item.Should().EndWith("-passed");
}
```

You might also want to maintain a count of how often it was called:

```
int called = 0;
list.ForEach(s => {
    dest.Add(x + "-passed");
    called++;
});

Assert.AreEqual(called, list.Count);
```

Comment: You should just be using `Select` if that's your goal.  The goal here is to test `ForEach`, but at the end of the day, that's not a problem that that method is designed to accomplish.  The test should really be changed from the ground up.

Comment: @Servy - Could you add a quick sample perhaps?

Comment: @Servy - Obviously you wouldn't use `ForEach` to do a projection normally, but the only thing you can really test is that the supplied action is invoked on each input element. So you need to have some effect you can assert on afterwards.

Comment: @Lee True.  So leave it at something more basic.  For example, in your second case, you aren't even asserting anything on the list.  Just increment in the action and asserting on *that* would be *a* valid test (but not really a valid test suite) that verifies the action is fired an appropriate number of times.  You'd also need to test that the action is invoked on each item exactly once, that exceptions are handled...however you want them to be handled, and whatever else you want to verify about the method.

Comment: @Servy - The second example is an extra assertion you could do. Yes, there are a few tests you could write, but I just explained the issue with the original code.

Comment: @Lee And yet the question isn't "why did this test fail?" but rather "how do I test this method?"  If it was the former, this would answer the question and the question would be appropriate for SO.  Since it's the latter this *doesn't* answer the question and it *isn't* an appropriate question for the site.

Comment: @Servy - The question says, "I have tried this, but no deal:".

Comment: Why is this not an appropriate question?

Comment: @Lee Yes it does say that.  That's not the question it asks though.  If the OP edited the question to remove that last line, or replace it with something along the lines of "why does this test not pass" then, as I said, it would make the question appropriate and your answer valid.

Comment: @SamStriano For starters it's too broad.  Trying to include in an answer an in-depth analysis of how to test methods in C# is something people write books about, not something that you can answer in just a paragraph or two.  It also seems like you're just asking us to do your work for you and write a bunch of tests for you.  Asking us to help you fix a particular test that isn't working is much more specific than the vague "how do I test this?" question.  As others have also indicate with their close votes, it's also unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> items = new List<int>();
Action<int> act = i => { items.Add(i); };

Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ForEach(act).ToList();

Assert.That(items.Count, Is.EqualTo(10));
...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this: `Action<int> act = i => { items.Add(i); };`? What does `i` mean? What does `=>` do?

Comment: That line creates the `Action<T>` object that is passed into the `ForEach<T>()` method. `=>` is a way to create an anonymous delegate that is of type `Action<T>`. `i` is the item value while enumerating the list. In this case, it is an `int` because `Enumerable.Range(0,10)` returns `IEnumerable<int>`.